# How to sum values in a column dataframe base on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set which has video games, their sales, and the year the game was released. I am only looking for the game sales per year, not the game sales per title per year.

I am using a pandas Dataframe. I have tried a groupby method. I have tried a loop with .unique() values.

```
df = df[["Year", "NA_Sales"]]
df.Year = df.Year.astype(int)
df2 = df
df2.Year = df.Year.unique()

df2 = df.groupby(['Year'])['NA_Sales'].sum()
```

The expected result would be a dataframe including one column of unique year values, and one column of all video game sales for that year

Comment: `df.groupby(['Year'])['NA_Sales'].sum().reset_index()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
df.groupby('Year', as_index=False)['NA_Sales'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd

path = r'your path'
wb = pd.read_excel(path)
df =  pd.DataFrame(wb)
df.style.hide_index()
df1 = df[['YEAR', 'NA_SALES']]
GB=df1.groupby([df1['YEAR']]).sum()
```

Make sure that when you create the `DataFrame` the `dtype` is not a `str`.